# Rendering performacne of Vegas MovieStudio 14

Tags: video-editor, vegas-pro, performance

**Issue Summary**

- I am testing MovieStudio 14
- I have a Dell M4500, i7, 8-core, 8Gb RAM, NVIDIA quadro
- Editing has good performance, no complaints.
- 9 minute video w/4 transitions and oldtime movie effect takes 12 hours to render HD quicktime.
- My machine does not grind to a halt while rendering.
- Per post I read,  I downgraded NVIDIA  driver, now it takes 5-6 hours to render.
- For comparison, I own Adobe premiere elements 12 on the same machine and that takes about 3-4 hours.

**Question**
I am asking how to improve the performace of MovieStudio 14?  Or any of these editing tools.

What I don't want to do is buy all new software and/or upgrades (or even a new laptop) if these tools need certain settings, drivers, optical drives or new hardware.

thanks

**UPDATE**

Thanks to everyones input I bought Vegas MovieStudio platinum 15, diabled all services not needed and installed my SSD.
I was able to render a 7 minute video in Quicktime HD in 70 minutes!  Acceptable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal, that different software outputs different results in different time ranges. Maybe the effect you use in AP Elements is much simpler than the one in MovieStudio. Or Movie Studio uses more ressources to run. Or the settings were not exactly equal.

In general you improve rendering perfomance with the following steps:

- Close internet connection
- Remove all media from the computer that is not needed for the rendering
- Deactivate temporarily all programs in background (e.g. anti virus) that are not needed ( ATTENTION: Don't take any risks. "Maybe" always means "Leave it!")
- Only open data that is directly related to the media you render. ( No other projects in background )
- Leave the system alone during work
- For Windows: Defrag Harddisk before rendering

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  Your last item:  I have a new optical drive.  Think that would help?

Comment: No, defrag only applies for harddisks, for other's like ssd it is harmful. You say optical drive - like DVD or BluRay? If it is USB, turn it off or unmount while rendering.

Comment: Thanks - No, I meant I have an internel optical HDD with running Win10 I can swap in&out

Comment: Basically: Remove or deactivate any redundant devices and programs, but BE CAREFUL to decide, whether something is redundant. And secondary: Use the "pipeline" with the most capacity in your workflow. Prefer internal devices instead of USB, use flash devices for swapping instead of the internal to get more data rate to the HDD. Such procedures can make a difference. And work non-destructive, make any operation you try reversible. ( This might even be an advise for editing, but I meant the performance issue this time. )

Comment: Thank you.  I can think of a few background process I can disable.

Comment: Opinion question for you, romeoyankee.  What editing software do you use?

Comment: An older version of Final Cut.

Answer (score 0):

12 hours render time for 9 minutes of HD footage is extrem, especially on that powerfull machine of yours. Either your "old time movie effect" is extremely demanding, or there's something seriously broken in your setup. I would expect a render time of far less than one hour.

Five guesses from my side:

1. You have a powerfull processor, and Vegas/Movie Studio is sometimes a bit special when it comes to GPU support, especially with CUDA. Try to disable GPU support and see what happens. Watch out though - there are multiple places where parts of the GPU support can be activated/deactivated in Vegas.
2. Check in the task manager, if indeed all of your 8 cores are active during rendering. You can set the number of render threads in the Movie Studio options. Maybe it's set to a low value. The optimum would be around 16 for your CPU.
3. Do a test run without the old time movie effect to see, whether this effect is the problem.
4. As romeoyankee already suggested: Try to figure out whether your AV software interferes with Movie Studio.
5. And just to be on the safe side: Check, whether there's enough available RAM during the render process. When the system needs to start swapping, this would have a huge impact on your performance. But with 8GB I doubt this is the case here.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  FYI: I cloned my HDD to a Samsung SSD.  And I removed the effect.  Rendered in 2 minutes.  Now I'm suspisious in the other direction.  That seems way to short to render HD.  My guess is that plug-in effect is buggy.